# The meaning of "out of question" vs "out of the question"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, definite-article

What is the difference between these two?

> out of question

versus

> out of the question

Does "out of question" mean "undoubtedly" and "out of the question" mean "impossible"?

Comment: "Out of question" feels unnatural. Could you include the context where you found it?

Comment: I haven't found it anywhere. I just felt I have heard it somewhere. I searched and seen it is the problem of others just like me. @A.McCurran

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's been discussed on [ELU, here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17711/is-it-out-of-question-or-out-of-the-question).

Apparently, "out of question" meant

> Beyond doubt, undoubtedly

but it is **obsolete**. [This](http://www.yourdictionary.com/out-of-question) says it is obsolete.

*Out of the question* is still in common use, in my opinion

> [out of the question](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+the+question)
> Not worth considering because of being too difficult or impossible:

Here is some ngram data
[image]

Comment: A minor comment: I often don't bother to click links (or hover my mouse over the links), so I'd prefer reading "[YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/out-of-question) says it is obsolete" instead of "[This](http://www.yourdictionary.com/out-of-question) says it is obsolete".

Comment: Interestingly, an alternative for **"out of question"** which I believe _is_ still in widespread usage would be **"not in question"**.

Comment: "Beyond question" (meaning "beyond doubt") is still [somewhat current](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+of+question%2Cbeyond+question%2Cout+of+the+question&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20question%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeyond%20question%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20the%20question%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 8):

*Out of the question* is the term in use today. It means *beyond consideration; unthinkable or impossible* ([Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/out-of-the-question)).

*Out of question* is obsolete, which means no longer used. When it was used, it had two meanings.

The first one was *unquestionably* or *doubtless*. See Definition 5 in [Universal Dictionary of the English Language](https://books.google.com/books?id=lEzlAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA3851&dq=%22out+of+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ7PbOnszNAhXH5iYKHWRoCmEQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22out%20of%20question%22&f=false). Today, for this meaning we use *without question*.

As you can see from Definition 6 from the same dictionary, it also meant *out of the question* or *not to be thought of*. So it was just a variation of the same phrase with the definite article. (As an aside, this shows how idiomatic the use of the definite article can be.)

The *Oxford English Dictionary* gives an example of *out of question*, as a variation of *out of the question*, as recently as 1940:

> Flight tests have shown that more than one glider can be towed by an aeroplane, so that a glider train is not out of question.

(from the magazine *Aeronautics*).

So, in general, you won't see *out of question* in use nowadays, but in older uses (that are now obsolete), it could mean either the same thing as *out of the question* or it could mean *unquestionably*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 'out of question' means undoubtedly, but its usage as such is obsolete.

It's also correct that the idiom 'out of the question' that's very common implies impossible.

If you say something is out of the question, it means it's not worth considering because of being too difficult or impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is:

> the

a fixed value: **out of** (    ) **question**

a variable: out of **the** question

So we only need to analyze and find out the usage and meaning of "**the**"

: **question** vs **the question**

'the question' means a specific qustion that all the parties, maybe, know what the question is. And 'question' without 'the' means not a specific question but a conceptual question.

In short, 'out of question' is without a question or without questions and 'out of the question' is without the question, which means 'the question(a specific question)' is not needed maybe because it is not worth considering or the question's quality is actually impossible.

Answer (score -3):

I think it is like this :

> **out of the question :** Not worth considering because of being too difficult or impossible

Example :

> ```
> Your answer is out of the question.
> ```
>
> In other word,
>
> ```
> "out of the question" do not relate to the question.
> ```

And the other hand :

> **out of questions :** You no longer have any questions at all.

Comment: No - if you no longer have any questions you are "out of questions" (with an "S").